# How to run headless firefox browser on remote server over SSH connection?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox

I have a remote server and I wish to run a headless session of Firefox there. I login into the remote server and execute the command. Even if the commands are headless, still it opens my machine's Firefox and performs actions within it. Any idea what could be the reason? I wish to perform these actions remotely without my display machine (like my laptop) being connected to it.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expected
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('-headless')
    driver = Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver', firefox_options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)
    driver.get('http://www.google.com')
    wait.until(expected.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'q'))).send_keys('headless firefox' + Keys.ENTER)
    wait.until(expected.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ires a'))).click()
    print(driver.page_source)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: options.add_argument("--headless")

Comment: Tried this as well. No luck

Comment: Have you tried this one:-                     options.set_headless(headless=True)

Comment: Yes. Problem is we are executing on end machine over SSH

Comment: You need to execute the code on remote machine and not locally on your machine

Comment: I execute it on remote machine

Comment: Two hyphens or single hyphen, it doesn't work

Comment: If I execute it on local machine it works perfectly. If on virtual server it doesn't work

Comment: I would suggest to use selenium grid for running selenium tests remotely.

Comment: Please check my answer to post. It resolved the issue I had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it myself as follows:

First run this in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
sudo pip3 install pyvirtualdisplay
```

Then add following lines to your code

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0,size=(1024,768))
display.start()
```

And my browser configuration looks like this:

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
display = Display(visible=0,size=(1024,768))
display.start()
options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
binary = FirefoxBinary("/home/ubuntu/firefox/firefox")
options.add_argument("-headless")
browser = Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/home/ubuntu/Documents/sourcecode/geckodriver',firefox_binary=binary,capabilities = cap )
```